# Inode Number Full Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, centos, redhat

I have a ubuntu machine with 8Gb of RAM and 250B of Harddisk. I am using this machine as my Jenkins Server for CI , Iam facing inode number full problem from the past few days

I fire command :

```
df -i
```

Output:

```
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      18989056 15327782 3661274   81% /
none             989841       11  989830    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             978914      465  978449    1% /dev
tmpfs            989841      480  989361    1% /run
none             989841        3  989838    1% /run/lock
none             989841        8  989833    1% /run/shm
none             989841       39  989802    1% /run/user
```

Suggest how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program [mkfs.ext4](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) allows an open `-N` which sets the number of inodes when making a new file system.

In this case you'd need to backup the entire `/` file system, boot from a live CD/USB and recreate the filesystem on `/dev/sda5`. **WARNING**: This will kill every single file on that drive. You'll probably need to reinstall the operating system onto that partition first because merely restoring a backup of a boot drive will likely not get all the fiddly bits necessary to boot.

If you are running out of inodes, it is likely you are doing something sub-optimal like using the filesystem as a poor-man's database. It is worth looking into why you are exhausting i-nodes, but that's another question.